# How to access a cell value from gspread

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, gspread

i would like to retrieve a cell value from gspread python API, however, the cell method "sheet.acell(A)" returns a value like this
sheet.acell(A)
i have proposed a forced solution in a way. is there a more efficient way to handle this

```
      def cellfinder(A):
            cell =str(sheet.acell(A))
            for x in cell:
               if x=="'":
                 f=cell[cell.index("'")+1:len(cell)-2]
                 return f
```

thank you

Answer (score 2):

I think you already might have figured this out, but in case if you didn't, it should be:

```
cell = sheet.acell('B1').value
```

Comment: Its been about a year, but I really appreciate the answer. thank you